Website proxied with NGINX shows 404 error on reload or when giving direct path address in AWS EC2
I am trying to host a react application in amazon ec2 instance. I am using docker and github workflow to update the site on github push .when the domain is typed  it loads the site without any problem what so ever and the navigation within the site works without problem.but when i try reloading the site or directly type the path on to the search bar like example.com/signin  it shows

404 Not Found
nginx/1.23.4
even if its staying on the same address.clicking links within the site loads other pages without any problem.
. my nginx config file looks like this

  /etc/nginx/sites-available/myApp.conf                                                              
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name {{servername}};

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://{{frond end port}};
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    }
    location /api {
        # Forward requests to backend server (e.g., running on port 4000)
        proxy_pass http://{{backend port address}};
    }
}

How can i fix it?
what i tried
i tried to set the config location / as
  location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }


and the root as
root /etc/nginx/index.html;

and all it did was show an nginx default page when entering the domain name .
also the react index.html is nowhere to be found since i am using docker image
i looked around in internet and found out the default nginx config overrides the custom one and tried deleting it. but it said permission denied. it was looking like this
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;        
listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #  
# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
 #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}

Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}

Is this any problem with this one?
